# search preference by Ctrl + ' in monodevelop

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm new to Unity. In MonoDevelop windows, when I select a text and press the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> , to search for reference, Firefox opens a new tab (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html).

Question: I want Firefox to open new tab link to file:///C:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/Unity/Editor/Data/Documentation/html/en/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html. How can I do that?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox's Redirector can be used to solve this problem. Use this config:

**Include Pattern:** http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/*

**Redirect To:** local URL

**Pattern Type:** Wildcard

**Link as reference:** http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/30436/launching-local-unity-api-reference-from-monodevel.html